What if a name is male but ends (-a)?
I have a friend which his name is Darma. A sanskrit name, should I use first declension? I doubt it because first declension is female noun.

Nouns in the first declension are usually feminine, but this is just a default rule: it's not obligatory. Latin speakers had no qualms about including male names in the first declension. Many Romans had such names, such as Sulla, Caligula, Galba, Nerva, Caracalla. Sometimes such names originate from a feminine common noun (caligula literally means 'small leather boot'), or sometimes they are borrowed from another language. In any case, it wouldn't be anything out of the norm to adapt a name Darma in Latin as a first-declension masculine Darma, Darmae.

How about the name which ends -o? like Hugo

@WilliamSukaryoPrasetyo: Hugo in Latin is declined as Hugo, Hugonis (third declension). That's a common pattern for names ending in -o but depending on the source name it could be adapted differently

How about the name with ending -i? like Giovanni, Levi

@WilliamSukaryoPrasetyo : For Giovanni, I would probably use the Latinization Ioannes. For Levi, it is often the case Hebrew names are indeclinable; but in this case, forms Levis (gen.) and Levin (acc.) appear.

@Asteroides: Did anyone call him Caligula to his face? Would that have been dangerous.? Dame Mary Beard's irreverent translation, "Bootykins", may be amusing to us; but, did it fit with Caius's image of himself?

There are such names in Latin, the most famous one probably being "Catilina" (one who supposedly made a massive conspiracy to kill Cicero). "Catilina" is declined by the first declension.

… as you can witness in Cicero's famous Orationes in Catilinam.
